# An extra radio circle appear when create a radio button in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-radio

When i create a radio button in  jQuery mobile, a radio circle appear in the next of the created radio as  appear in the photo , why this extra radio circle appear ?  how can i solve this ?? please help me ...

[image]

```
 <fieldset>
 <legend> Gender </legend>
 <div class="ui-grid-a">
 <div class="ui-block-a  ">  
 <input type="radio"   id="Male"    name="radio-group-1"  value="Male" />
 <label  for="Male"    data-inline="true">Male</label>
 </div>
 <div class="ui-block-b">
 <input  type="radio"    id="Female" name="radio-group-1"  value="Female" />
 <label  for="Female"    data-inline="true" >Female</label>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: check your css, it looks like you're overriding something. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/spxcL/

Comment: @OmarCheck this http://jsfiddle.net/spxcL/3/  its appear in jsfiddle also .

Comment: override `.ui-radio` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/spxcL/4/

Comment: @OmarThanks,but it still check this http://jsfiddle.net/spxcL/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/spxcL/6/ hide native radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `.ui-radio` class when you want to change radio button position.

```
.ui-radio {
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
}
```

Hide radio buttons with a transparent background

```
.ui-radio input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/hFw9P/)**